# visual c++ an unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to transform my C# implementation of Levenstein algorithm into Visual C++ and I am facing this error message

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred
```

The original fully working C# code is

```
public static int Compute(string s, string t)
{
    int n = s.Length;
    int m = t.Length;
    int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

    // Step 1
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return m;
    }

    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
    {
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
    {
    }

    // Step 3
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        //Step 4
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            // Step 5
            int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            // Step 6
            d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    // Step 7
    return d[n, m];
}
```

Visual C++ code that produces `IndexOutOfRangeException` is this

```
int Compute(String^ s, String^ t)
{
    int n = s->Length;
    int m = t->Length;

    array<int,2>^ d = gcnew array<int,2>(n+1 , m+1); //int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

    // Step 1
    if (n == 0)
    {
       return m;
    }

    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
    {
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
    {
    }

    // Step 3
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        //Step 4
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
        // Step 5
        int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

        // Step 6
        d[i, j] = Math::Min(
            Math::Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
            d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    // Step 7
    return d[n, m];
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my array declaration in Visual C++?

Comment: In which step does the exception occurr?

Comment: @Stephan checked it and it happens in the all for loops I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soved it , I used vectors instead or array
my 2D array implementation was not corrected , here is the correct implementation in visual C++

```
        int Lev(String^ s, String^ t)
    {
        int n = s->Length;
        int m = t->Length;

        vector<vector<int> > d(n+1,vector<int>(m+1));
        // Step 1
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return m;
        }

        if (m == 0)
        {
            return n;
        }

        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i][0] = i++)
        {
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0][j] = j++)
        {
        }

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
            // Step 5
            int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            // Step 6
            d[i][j] = Math::Min(
                Math::Min(d[i - 1][j] + 1, d[i][j - 1] + 1),
                d[i - 1][j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7

        return d[n][m];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs because of accessing the index more than its limit.
e.g. limit is n and you are using n+1 th element of an array.

`check the value of i and j does it exceeds or and m+1`  print the values of i and j so that you can find in which iteration the value exceeds limit.

Comment: I know the exception is because index out of bound but I need to transform the code without changing anything on the algorithm
is there anything with my declaration of the array in Visual c